# Spring Web no esta funcionando correctamente

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

Estoy trabajando en proyectos con Spring boot y Spring web principalmente, hice un proyecto sencillo solo para entender el funcionamiento de spring y no me funciona. no sale ningun error inicializa el servidor pero no hace el return del servicio rest.

Adjunto mi POM

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-start

er-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.13.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>init.product</groupId>
<artifactId>hulkstore</artifactId>
<version>1</version>
<name>hulkstore</name>
<description>Api Hulk Store</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Clase REST

```
    package com.yefersoncm.rest;

    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public class UserRest {

        @GetMapping
        public String helloWorld() {
            return "Hello World";
        }

}
```

Main

```
package com.yefersoncm.hulkstore;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HulkstoreApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HulkstoreApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Al correr ejecutar como Spring Boot Aplication sale lo siguiente

```
2020-04-12 10:49:11.539  INFO 403080 --- [           main] c.y.hulkstore.HulkstoreApplication       : Starting HulkstoreApplication on LAPTOP-HBBAHBR4 with PID 403080 (C:\Users\Yefersonft\eclipse-workspace\hulkstore\target\classes started by Yefersonft in C:\Users\Yefersonft\eclipse-workspace\hulkstore)
2020-04-12 10:49:11.539  INFO 403080 --- [           main] c.y.hulkstore.HulkstoreApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-04-12 10:49:12.498  INFO 403080 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-04-12 10:49:12.522  INFO 403080 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-04-12 10:49:12.522  INFO 403080 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.31]
2020-04-12 10:49:12.647  INFO 403080 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-04-12 10:49:12.647  INFO 403080 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1061 ms
2020-04-12 10:49:12.866  INFO 403080 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-04-12 10:49:13.053  INFO 403080 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-04-12 10:49:13.053  INFO 403080 --- [           main] c.y.hulkstore.HulkstoreApplication       : Started HulkstoreApplication in 1.834 seconds (JVM running for 2.716)
2020-04-12 10:49:16.975  INFO 403080 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-04-12 10:49:16.976  INFO 403080 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-04-12 10:49:16.984  INFO 403080 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 8 ms
```

Segun yo, no hay ningun error segun eso, el Tomcat se inicia pero el rest no funciona, no me retorna el hola mundo, quisiera saber que puedo estar haciendo mal, ya intente con `ResponseEntity<String>` en el método y no funciona tampoco.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que al tener los controlladores en un paquete diferente al de la clase anotada con `@SpringBootApplication`, y que a la vez no es un subpaquete de este, no se está creando el Bean del controllador REST, ya que el mecanismo de ComponentScan no lo encuentra.

Tienes que entender dos cosas:

**1 - Uso de `@SpringBootApplication`**

Esta anotación es un alias de tres anotaciones (o sea, es lo mismo que agregar explícitamente las tres anotaciones) que son las que permiten el funcionamiento básico de las aplicaciones de Spring Boot:

- `@EnableAutoConfiguration`
- `@ComponentScan`
- `@Configuration`

**2 - Funcionamiento de `@ComponentScan`**

Esta anotación permite escanear el proyecto en busca de componentes de Spring (clases anotadas con @Component, @Service, @Repository, @Controller etc.) y registrar el Bean correspondiente en el contexto de la aplicación. Pero lo importante aquí es que dicho escaneo se hace en el paquete de la clase anotada con esta anotación y en todos sus subpaquetes. Esto quiere decir que cualquier componente fuera estos paquetes no serán encontrados.

**Solución**

A mi siempre me gusta tener la clase principal de la aplicación (la anotada con `@SpringBootApplication`) en el paquete raíz y el resto de clases las meto en subpaquetes de este:

```
com.myapp
    +-rest
    |    |-RestController.java
    |
    +-repository
    |    |-UserRepo.java
    |
    |-Application.java
```

De este modo al anotar la clase `Application` con `@SpringBootApplichation` todos los componentes que hayas definido en el resto de paquetes serán encontrados sin problema.

Si por alguna razón quieres mantener tu estructura de directorios debes entonces agregar explícitamente la anotación `@ComponentScan` e indicarle cuales paquetes debe escanear (de igual modo se cumple la regla de escaneo de subpaquetes).

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.yefersoncm")
public class HulkstoreApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HulkstoreApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me sirvio mucho, siempre he hecho cosas con spring y no tenia ni idea de el component scan, no sabia que eso afectaba, lo tendre encuenta.